# New CCK fileds not showing up on Creat Content form

Tags: drupal, content-type, field, cck

I have created new fields for a CCK content type. They were showing up before just fine. Now nothing. The only thing I did differently was delete some fields before adding the new ones.
I can see the columns in the content type table. They are just not showing up in the Create Content form. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I Solved it! Stinkin permissions got me again!

With drupal it is necessary to give permission for these fields to be seen by even someone with admin role. I made this adjustment at:

/admin/user/permissions

I hope i save someone some time with that.  : )

Comment: You don't need to worry about permissions on a field level if you simply disable the content permissions module.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the Content Permissions if you want. Even though it can be a pain, you will appreciate the granular permissions when you need it.